# Change CSF-LFD ports safely with sed

Tags: sed, security, firewall

I've installed CSF-LFD as described [here](https://download.configserver.com/csf/install.txt). in `/etc/csf/csf.conf` You have these two code blocks:

```
# Allow incoming TCP ports
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2077,2078,2079,2080,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,2096"

# Allow outgoing TCP ports
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,113,443,587,873,993,995,2086,2087,2089,2703"
```

I need both port groups to be changed just to `"22, 80, 443, 9000"` to make sure my Nginx server environment allows incoming data only from these ports.

What's the best, safest way to do that with `sed`?

I think that this is a good way:

```
sed -i 's/^TCP_IN = .*/TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' /etc/csf/csf.conf
sed -i 's/^TCP_OUT = .*/TCP_OUT = "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' /etc/csf/csf.conf
```

Yet, given `csf.conf` is a huge file and might have huge potential for changes, there might be a tiny better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done is one pass with **`sed`**:

```
sed -Ei 's/^(TCP_(IN|OUT) = ).*/\1"22, 80, 443, 9000"/' /etc/csf/csf.conf
```

- `(IN|OUT)` - regex alternation group, matches either `IN` or `OUT` substring
- `\1` - backreference, references the 1st captured group `(...)`